# Designing tool for C#

Tags: c#, design, tools

I have seen few developers use a tool for designing their application where they simply dragged needed elements (classes, variables, objects) and just did magic work.

Then there was a button to generate a code where the design was generated into a C# code after what developer continued to work on software manually.

Anyone can give me an idea about what those are called and where I may grab one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studios does just that with their layout blocking stuff - if you feel like paying for it or have a student MSDNAA licence. Otherwise, I think netBeans allows for this as well (at least last time I used netBeans it did) and is free.

Comment: I have visual studio pro 2010 as well as 2008. But I don't even have an idea what is the name of that feature.

Comment: @jM2.me It's just your toolbox, it appears whenever you start a new project, if it's not there you can usually find it under "toolbars" in "view" or under "tools." All of the application designers will be in some sort of IDE (netBeans, VS, Eclipse, etc)

Comment: Sorry - how exactly does Visual Studio allow you to 'drag needed elements' to create 'classes, variables and objects'?

Comment: @Kirk The toolbox allows for barebones object design.  Say you want to create some interactive window, you can drag and drop all the necessary items (buttons, text boxes, etc) and can even put in a large portion of the "logic glue" between a button submitting text and what not without even typing one bit of actual code.

Comment: Yes, a designer for basic UI.  This can implicitly create classes, but I don't know about variables or objects.  This question seems kind of suspect.

Comment: You can also place macro's on the toolbox, perhaps those were used

Comment: The designer is not just for UI components, but for all components.

Comment: @jM2.me: It's called the designer and it's the reason Visual Studio is called "Visual" Studio.  There are various GUI designers for the various GUI technologies VS supports.

Answer (score 0):

Might they have been using a UML modelling tool which can generate C# code, like [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) or [Rational Software Architect](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/products/swarchitect/)?

Comment: Nope, the OP means visual programming.